# What is the name of the background music for episode "The Die is Cast" in Sekai-ichi Hatsukoi

Tags: music, sekai-ichi-hatsukoi

What is the background music in Sekai-ichi Hatsukoi Season 1 episode 9 at 18:07? When Yukina Kou confesses his love to Kisa Shouta.

Answer (score 0):

This song is from the sekaiichi hatsukoi soundtrack ost 1 track 23.